# How to locate and view java packages and classes within fedora?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, package

I am trying to connect my java program with a mysql database in a fedora 16 machine. When I executed my program it returned the error "com.myql.jdbc.Driver not found". I downloaded mysql-connector-java.jar file that contains the classes mentioned above. Where should i place the package after extracting?

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar in classpath which is available at runtime

Comment: I had tried your suggestion, but it didn't work either. Anyway I solved the problem by extracting the package to the directory where my java program is stored, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Java Classloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader)?

If you think it will be used often, you could consider putting it in (JRE JAVA FOLDER)/lib/ext (According to the 2nd types of classes mentioned in Wiki page)